# Extract the part of string matched by % in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am doing my CS homework, which consists of a lot of single-file programs. My working directory looks like this:

```
133.c 134.c 220.c 281.c 337.c 338.c 339.c makefile
```

And I wrote a Makefile like this:

```makefile
%: %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^
```

So when I want to compile the program for Question 220, I type this:

```
ibug@wsl:~ $ make 220
gcc  -o 220 220.c
ibug@wsl:~ $
```

## Question

I want to write a `clean-%` rule so that when I run this in shell, the result should look like below

```
ibug@wsl:~ $ make clean-133
rm -f 133
ibug@wsl:~ $ make clean-281
rm -f 281
ibug@wsl:~ $ make clean-337
rm -f 337
```

I've gone so far with this:

```
.PHONY: clean-%

SRC = $(wildcard %.c)
BIN = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRC))

clean-%:
    rm -f ??????
```

What should I put in place of the question marks?

I'm using GNU Make 4.1 (on Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [automatic variable `$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), which contains the *stem* (i.e., the part matched against `%`):

```
clean-%:
    rm -f $*
```

However, keep reading.

---

### Phony targets, patterns and implicit rules

Adding the prerequisite `clean-%` to the `.PHONY` target:

```
.PHONY: clean-%
```

does not turn the *pattern rule* `clean-%` into a *phony target*, but rather turns the *explicit* rule, whose actual target name is `clean-%` (not a pattern), into a phony target.

The reason is that only targets of *explicit rules* can be made phony targets, a pattern can't be a phony target. So, a phony target that looks like a pattern (i.e., contains `%`) is not really a pattern (i.e., the `%` is literally a `%`).

Adding all the possible values `clean-%` could be matched against to `.PHONY` won't help either, because *phony targets* do **not** match *implicit pattern rules*. So, if you do:

```
.PHONY: clean-foo
```

`clean-foo` will never match an implicit pattern rule (i.e., it will never match your `clean-%` pattern rule).

---

### Defining `clean-xxx` as phony targets

I guess you actually want these `clean-xxx` targets to be *phony targets*, since these targets do not represent actual files on the file system.

#### Using a static pattern rule

Unlike implicit pattern rules, [*static pattern rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html#Static-versus-Implicit) can match phony targets. The following approach consists of defining a single static pattern rule that can match those `clean-xxx` phony targets:

```
list := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

# list of clean-xxx targets
clean-targets := $(addprefix clean-,$(list))

.PHONY: $(clean-targets)

$(clean-targets): clean-%:
    rm -f $*
```

The static pattern rule above will match any of the `clean-xxx` phony targets specified in its list of targets (i.e., the  `$(clean-targets)`.

#### Using explicit rules

The following approach consists of dynamically generating these `clean-xxx` rules as explicit rules instead of a single pattern rule:

```
list := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

define create-clean-target
    $(eval .PHONY: clean-$1);
    $(eval clean-$1:; rm -f $1)
endef


# dynamically generate the clean-xxx targets
$(foreach t,$(list),$(call create-clean-target,$t))
```

The user-defined function `create-target` defines an *explicit* target `clean-xxx`, being `xxx` the argument passed to the function. Since this target to be defined is an explicit target, it can be made a *phony* target as well.

Comment: Why are you doing all this call and eval stuff?  I really think these advanced topics should be avoided until and unless they're truly needed, especially for people who are just learning.  These topics are tricky even for experienced makefile writers to understand.  What the OP wants can be trivially done without needing any of this, just write `.PHONY: $(addprefix clean-,$(list))` and the clean pattern rule they already had (with `$*`)

Comment: @MadScientist That was my initial approach, but it seems that after doing `.PHONY: $(addprefix clean-,$(list)`, the pattern rule `clean-%` doesn't match for those targets anymore (the pattern rule doesn't seem to match phony targets). Am I missing something more fundamental here?

Comment: You may need to use a static pattern rule instead of a normal pattern rule: `$(addprefix clean-,$(list)): clean-%: ; echo clean $*`  IMO this is still simpler than call/eval...

Comment: @MadScientist Great! I agree, your approach using the the static pattern rule is the simplest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With your file naming convention **you don't need any makefile**, since [GNU Make's built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) already do what you want. Try this:

```
$ mv Makefile Makefile.bak
$ rm -f 220
$ make 220       # make magic happening here!
$ rm -f 220
$ make CC=cc CFLAGS="-Wall -O2" 220
```

As you can see, *make* knows how to turn *foo*.c into a *foo* executable with a C compiler.

To retrieve the list of builtin rules, run `make -p` without a Makefile present.

As for cleaning your executables, why be so verbose and type `make clean-NNN` when `rm -f NNN` or maybe `rm -f [0-9]??` is about as much to type?

Comment: `make -p` gave me all I needed.